# jquery и bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Здравствуйте. Вчера приступил к изучение jquery и почти сразу же возник вопрос. Могут ли jquery и bootstrap каким-либо образом конфликтовать? Если да, то каким? Просто даже подобный код, типа того, что ниже, не выполняется.

```
$('.classname').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

На первом месте по конфликтам в js-библиотеках (на моём скромном опыте) - ошибки при написании пользовательских скриптов. На втором - использование **$** в различном контексте.

Освобождение переменной $:

> $.noConflict();

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    // Далее можно использовать $ другой библиотеки
</script>
```

или

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Код jQuery с использованием $
    });
    // Код другой JavaScript-библиотеки
</script>
```

Вот [Очень Понятная Статья](http://w3pro.ru/book/spravochnik-po-jquery-api/jquerynoconflict)

НО! В вашем случае я бы начал с проверки кода. Загляните в консоль - там живёт правда)